# CheckBox OnLongClick Behavior

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a list of items disposed vertically. Each item has a CheckBox and a TextView.
I'm trying to achieve a LongClick behavior for the CheckBox. More precisely i want it to change it with a trash icon while is LongClicked. On release it must become again a checkBox and also maintain the Check/Uncheck behavior on simple click.

How can i achieve that? How many approaches are there?
I apriciate any king of help!

---

I tried to just use setBackgroud() function, but it would just draw under the existing checkbox view, with the box still remaining on the top.

```
cb.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Resources res = tmp_context.getResources();
                Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_trash);
                cb.setBackground(drawable);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @ObscureGeek I tried to use setBackgroud() but the checkbox image remains on top, as i just draw underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

First Put your chekcbox inside a framelayout :

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/one"
    android:id="@+id/fl">
    <CheckBox

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Two"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/two"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

you could use LongClickListener and OnTouchListener:

```
private View.OnLongClickListener pressHoldListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View pView) {
        // Do something when your hold starts here.
        isSpeakButtonLongPressed = true;
        mFrameLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.trash_can);
        yourCheckBox.setVisibility(VIEW.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
};

private View.OnTouchListener pressTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View pView, MotionEvent pEvent) {
        pView.onTouchEvent(pEvent);
        // We're only interested in when the button is released.
        if (pEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // We're only interested in anything if our speak button is currently pressed.
            if (isSpeakButtonLongPressed) {
                // Do something when the button is released.
                yourCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mFrameLayout.setBackground(null);
                isSpeakButtonLongPressed = false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Inside you onCreate() :

```
yourCheckBox.setOnLongClickListener(pressHoldListener);  
yourCheckBox.setOnTouchListener(pressTouchListener);
```

Also add

```
android:longClickable="true"
```

to your checkbox xml.

Comment: @Akihil Soman thank you, but setBackgroundResource would still set only the backgroud of the CheckBox. While the check box remains intact on the top.

Comment: You could put your chexkbox inside a framelayout and then during long click set background to the framelayout and make the checkbox invisible. When releasing set background of framelayout to null, and make the checkbox visible.  I have UPDATED my code Please check.

Comment: Soaman Thank you it works! However i have generated a bug. I also have a setOnCheckedChangeListener on the checkbox and when press the checkbox, onCheckedChanged is called 2 times. So it checks and unchecks in one single click. Do you know how to solve this bug?

Comment: nevermind it works, i just have to return true in onTouch method!